# Can Bitcoin full nodes pinpoint the true source of a transaction which they've relayed?

Tags: transactions, full-node

Assume I'm running a full node and that I've relayed some transactions. As a full node owner, can I pinpoint the true source of the transactions I've relayed?

Comment: Without knowing what you mean by "true source", this question is not really possible to answer. Do you mean what machine introduced it to the Bitcoin network or where it was formed/signed?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the bitcoin data directory there is a file called `debug.log`.
This file as noted in the bitcoin documentation:

> May contain IP addresses and transaction ID's.

This does not indicate that a transaction originated from a specific IP address but it does indicate that your node received a transaction from that IP address.  If someone were to have a wide enough view of the network and controlled enough nodes then it could be inferred that the creator of a specific transaction was using a specific IP at the time.  This is not always considered conclusive evidence at this time.